# how to use float8 in postgres c user define function

Tags: c, postgresql, stored-functions

I am newer to postgres server programing and I want to achieve double+1;
here is the code copy from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xfunc-c.html.

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "utils/geo_decls.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

float8 *
add_one_float8(float8 *arg)
{
    float8    *result = (float8 *) palloc(sizeof(float8));

    *result = *arg + 1.0;//if replace *arg with 1.5, it return normal(2.5)

    return result;
}
```

I successfully create function.Everytimes I call function,the section was killed by postgres.

Then I try to replace float8 *arg with float8 and then call function with statement

```
select add_one(1.5);
```

it return 1;
it seems to arg is 0.And then I replace it with the following code

```
float8
add_one_float8(float8 arg)
{
    if(arg>0){
        return arg+2;
    }else if(arg==0)
        return arg+3;
    else
        return arg+4;
}
```

and then it return 2;
I have no idea how to handle float8 or double in postgres,does anybody know how to fix it or what neccessary step I missed?Thanks advance.

By the way, both postgresql-9.5 and 9.6 I tries,the result is the same.Platform is linux,centos7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#idm46428687639680), you need to use `PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(0)` to get the argument and `PG_RETURN_FLOAT8` to return the result.

Comment: Thank you Albe,use Version 1 Calling Conventions works, however I still doesn't understand why use Version 0 Calling Conventions raise such error.

Comment: I don't either, since I never used version 0. But then I have only worked with PostgreSQL for the last 15 years. Honestly, Version 0 has been deprecated for so long that you should not use it. It might go away some time soon.